# Can't edit Form1 textbox from Form2

Tags: c#, winforms

In Form1 I have a textbox filled with char array values (*). Then in Form2 I change one of the array values (change * to some letter) and I have to update Form1 textbox. But when I press button - nothing happens. Form2 code snippet:

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            .... 
            ....

            letter = (char)Form1.number;  
            textbox1.Text = letter.ToString(); //shows me the letter I'm replacing '*' with
        }


private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frm1 = new Form1();

            Form1.charArray[Convert.ToInt32(frm1.numericUpDown2.Value)] = letter; //which array value I'm changing

            frm1.textBox2.Text = String.Empty;

            for (int i = 0; i < frm1.numericUpDown1.Value; i++)
            {
                frm1.textBox2.Text += Form1.charArray[i];
            }
        }
```

Comment: You are not editing the `Form1`-instance that is visible to you. Instead, you **create** a new one here and change that (but never show it - which would result in two `Form1`-windows visible)

Comment: so I have to edit the line like **Form1**.textBox2.Text += Form1.charArray[i] ?

Comment: That probably would work if you declared `textBox2` static and assigned it the right value... read my answer for further options :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of editing the `Form1`-window you are talking about, you are creating a **new** (yet invisible) one in your event-handler and perform your operations on that.

**Solution:**

As you are already doing with some fields (`charArray`, `number`), you have to give this method "access" to the very instance of `Form1` that already exists!

*Option 1:*
As you have done with the `charArray` and `number`, add a static field to `Form1` (something like `public static Form1 instance;`), and assign to it the correct instance. For example, put `Form1.instance = this;` inside of `Form1`'s constructor.

*Option 2:*
Wherever you are creating and showing your `Form2`-window (I guess there is something like `new Form2().Show()` in your code and I bet it has access to your instance of `Form1` - maybe you even do this from *within* `Form1`), you could pass the right instance of `Form1` as a constructor argument, i.e. you change `Form2`'s constructor so it accepts a parameter of type `Form1` and then call `new Form2(theRightInstanceOfForm1)`.

*Summary:*
Although "Option 2" is definitely the cleaner one, I guess it will give you more trouble than "Option 1": Not only did you already define several static fields (so it would not really make a difference to add another one), if you are using the Visual Studio Designer to design `Form2`, it will break as soon as you change its constructor...

Comment: I would avoid option 1 if possible - `static` fields will cause you more trouble in the long run. Option 2 is the way to go, IMHO.